# Discord.py reacting to most recent message

Tags: discord, discord.py, message

I need help reacting to the most recent message. This can be in a specified channel or just in the server. The main thing I need help with is getting the message id or info about the most recent message, the reacting part I can do.

Please let me know if there is a solution, as everything I have looked up hasnt produced any results.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is missing a lot of information, Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include every piece of code you think is relevant while also keeping the question short and easy to understand. Give it an honest try before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few methods to get the last message in a channel. Assuming you already have a specific channel in which you want to react. Use

```py
last_message = channel.last_message #channel must be a discord.Channel
```

The docs specify that this could sometimes get the wrong message, hence we use

```py
messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()[0]
```

### References:

- [last_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.last_message)
- [history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.history)

Tip:
Try searching for the relevant class in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) instead of googling